# trying to insert values into table

Tags: sql, insert

I am trying to inserting value enter in  textbox  into table  like this

```
"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPassType_Name) VALUES('"+tbPassType.Text"'");
```

it was giving error like ";" missed

Comment: @haim I was just about to post this.. :)

Comment: It's important that you use parameters rather than string concatenation (unless you properly escape your inputs), or your code will be open to SQL injection.

Comment: BEWARE! SQL INJECTION! What if the value typed into tbPassType was: `1'); delete from guestpasstypes; select '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Insert into guestpasstypes (guestPassType_Name) values ('" + tbPassType.Text + "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a concatenation operator:

```
"Insert INTO guestpasstypes(guestPassType_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "');";
```

Comment: Also kindly not that if tbPassType is a user input your should sanitize it before putting it in your sql. Since it looks like .NET you are using you might want to consider stored procedures or LINQ :)

Comment: sql = @"Insert INTO guestpasstypes(guestPassType_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "'");  it was giving error like this  " invalid expression term ')'  "

Comment: There is an extra quote after +, you have to give it after the bracket

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  guestpasstypes(guestPassType_Name) VALUES ('"+tbPassType.Text+"')"
```

The second quote should be outside the parantheses

Answer (score 0):

If your going to carry on with this type of programming use

```
"Insert INTO guestpasstypes(guestPassType_Name)values('"+tbPassType.Text"')";
```

Otherwise, you should definitely look into sanitizing your sql.